# How to keep the zipped file's name after extracting it?

Tags: python, zip

I have a zip file named `model_A.zip`, which is renamed from `model_B.zip` . The original folder, which is to zip `model_B.zip`, is `model_B`. I use `zipfile` to extract it.

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('model_A.zip', "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(path_to_unzip)
```

After extracting it, the folder's name becomes `model_B/`. However, what I want is `model_A/`. I can use functions like `shutil.move(model_B, model_A)`, but the problem is I don't know the folder name after extracting (if `model_A.zip` is renamed from `model_C.zip`, the folder name is `model_C`).

Is there a way to get `model_A` without extra operations?

Comment: My guess is that the problem isn't that it's _renamed_ from `model_B.zip`. The problem is that the zip file _contains_ a folder called `model_B` because that's the folder that was added to it originally. The default name, then, was `model_B.zip` but that isn't linked to the folder inside it. Whatever folder you extract it to, the contents of the zip file will be in a subfolder called `model_B`. You could verify this by opening the zip file in a GUI

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yeah, that's an import information I have forgotten. I will edit my post.

Comment: *What* folder's name becomes `model_B`? The name of a zip file has no bearing on the names of the members within it. Anyway, it seems like `zip_ref.extractall('model_A')` would do what you want.

Comment: @martineau `zip_ref.extractall('model_A')` would add a subfolder, the result will be `model_A/model_B/`

Comment: I don't think that is true — did you actually try it? Also, what does `print(zip_ref.namelist())` show?

Comment: @martineau you seem want comment in the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What I gather from your question is that there is a single top file/directory in your zip file. After or during extraction, you wish to rename that file/directory. If getting the name of this top file is your objective, then maybe the following code can help. You can rename this file/directory after the extraction is complete.

```
import zipfile
import os

path_to_unzip ="D:\\Codes"
zip_file_loc = 'D:\\Codes\\Solo\\File_Sorter2.zip'
rename = "model"
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_loc, "r") as zip_ref:
    topdir = zip_ref.namelist()[0]
    if(topdir[-1] == '/'):
        topdir = topdir[:-1]
    zip_ref.extractall(path_to_unzip)
sp = topdir.split('.')
if len(sp)>1:
    rename = "model" + "." + sp[len(sp) - 1]
oldname = os.path.join(path_to_unzip, topdir)
newname = os.path.join(path_to_unzip, rename)
print(newname)
try:
    os.rename(oldname, newname)
except:
    print("Check if file already exists")
```

Comment: Seems there is error in your answer, can you verify and then edit?

Comment: It was working fine in my system. Nevertheless, I have provided the entire python file now. This should definitely work now. Be sure to provide the correct zip file location and unzip path directory. Please note that path_to_unzip is a directory. Also, hereon, please specify which error you get.